# RuntimeException on a composer update

Tags: composer-php, symfony4

When I do a composer update on an existing project I have this RuntimeException:

```
Could not delete /home/deepak/formation_symfony_4/SF4C4_hangman_begin/hangman/vendor/symfony/contracts/LICENSE
```

So, it must be a permission problem. I did a ls -al on the vendor folder and I have this result:

```
total 104
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  178  3 août  00:27 autoload.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 composer
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 doctrine
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 easycorp
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 egulias
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 jdorn
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 monolog
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 myclabs
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 nikic
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 ocramius
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 phar-io
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 phpdocumentor
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 phpspec
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 phpunit
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 psr
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 sebastian
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 sensio
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 swiftmailer
drwxr-xr-x 55 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 symfony
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 theseer
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 twig
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 webmozart
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096  3 août  00:27 zendframework
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `vendor` directory is owned by `root` so you have three options:

## Run `composer` as `root`.

Composer runs with elevated privileges, unnecessarily. This isn't good practice.

## Make `vendor` writeable by anyone:

```sh
sudo chmod -R o+w vendor
```

Anyone can modify `vendor` contents, which are presumably run automatically without much scrutiny. Again, bad security practice.

## Change the ownership of `vendor` to the user you want to run `composer` as:

```sh
sudo chown -R <user:group> vendor
```

Comment: I runned composer update as root and I have another exception: [ErrorException]                                                                                                                                                                           
  is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/root/.composer) is not within the allowed path(s): (/srv/http/:/home/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/share/webapps/:/etc/webapps/:/usr/bin/composer:/usr/local/bin/symfony:/dev/null)

Comment: Don't run it as `root`. Change the ownership of the directory.

Comment: I did `chown -R deepak:deepak vendor` and `composer update`. It functions better but I have another exception `[ErrorException]                                                         file_put_contents(./composer.lock): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: You need to change the ownership of `composer.lock` as well: `chown deepak:deepak composer.lock`

Comment: I have the same problem with some other folders and I changed the ownership too. Finally, it functions. Thank you.